# Python - regex to grab specific lines from text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to grab specific details being parsed in from email bodies, in this case the emails are plain text and formatted like so:

```
imbad@regex.com
John Doe
+16073948374
2021-04-27T15:38:11+0000
14904
```

The above is an example output of print(body) parsed in from an email like so:

```
def parseEmail(popServer, msgNum):
    raw_message=popServer.retr(msgNum)[1]
    str_message=email.message_from_bytes(b'\n'.join(raw_message))
    body=str(str_message.get_payload())
```

So, if I needed to simply grab the email address and phone number from body object, how might I do that using regex?

I understand regex is most certainly overkill for this, however I'm only repurposing an existing in-house utility that's already written to utilize regex for more complex queries, so it seems the simplest solution here would to modify the regex to grab the desired text. attempts to utilize str.partition() resulted in other unrelated errors.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get an e-mail address from the headers of the e-mail, or from the body of the e-mail (which I assume is what you have shown above)?

Comment: A simple RE like `\S+@\S+\.\S+` is crude, but should capture the e-mail address.

Comment: everything is parsed in from the body of the email, the example above is literally the contents of the email message. I need to assign first and third lines to new variables/objects to be used elsewhere in the program

Comment: Is it always on the first and third line, or is the format variable?

Comment: @joanis always first and third line

Comment: Then how about `lines = body.split('\n')`? Then e-mail is `lines[0]` and phone is `lines[2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following regex patterns:

For the email: `\.+@.+\n/g`

For the phone number: `\^[+]\d+\n/gm`

Remove the Initial forward slash if using in python re library.

Note in the email one only the global flag is used, but for the phone number pattern, the multiline flag is also used.

Simply loop over every body, capturing these details and storing them how you like.

Comment: thank you- and this can be used with re.search()? or does it have to be re.match()? Excuse my ignorance if that's a dumb question but I'm not so versed in regex

Comment: Since it's a multiline string, you'd be using re.search().

Answer (score 2):

In the comments clarifying the question, you indicated that the e-mail address is always on the first line, and the phone number is always on the 3rd line. In that case, I would just split the lines instead of trying to match them with an RE.

```py
lines = body.split("\n")
email = lines[0]
phone = lines[2]
```

Comment: I ended up using your solution, because well, duh. Thank you so much. From a practical standpoint, your answer is the obvious choice... however I need to give the answer to BrickleRex, as his solution worked for the question I specifically asked using regex (as senseless as using regex for this might be).

Comment: All good! Regexes are a powerful tool, one of my favourites, and I'm glad someone else answered the question as asked too.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """imbad@regex.com
John Doe
+16073948374
2021-04-27T15:38:11+0000
14904"""

ptrn = re.compile(r"(\w+@\w+\.[a-z]+|\+\d{11}\b)")
print(ptrn.findall(s))
```

**Output:**

```
['imbad@regex.c', '+16073948374']
```

Answer (score 1):

To match those patterns on the 1st and the 3rd line you can use 2 capture groups using a single regex:

```
^([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)\r?\n.*\r?\n(\+\d+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)` Capture an email like pattern in **group 1** (Just a single @ on the first line)
- `\r?\n.*\r?\n` Match (do not capture) the second line
- `(\+\d+)` Capture a `+` and 1+ digits in **group 2**
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YD2ulb/1)

Example

```
import re

regex = r"^([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)\r?\n.*\r?\n(\+\d+)$"

s = ("imbad@regex.com\n"
     "John Doe\n"
     "+16073948374\n"
     "2021-04-27T15:38:11+0000\n"
     "14904")

match = re.match(regex, s, re.MULTILINE)

if match:
        print(f"{match.group(1)}, {match.group(2)}")
```

Output

```
imbad@regex.com, +16073948374
```